# How to add custom EXIF tags to a image

Tags: c#, image, metadata, exif

I'd like to add a new tag ("LV95_original") to an image ( JPG, PNG or something else..)

How can I add a custom EXIF tag to a image?

This is what I've tried so far:

```
using (var file = Image.FromFile(path))
{
    PropertyItem propItem = file.PropertyItems[0];
    propItem.Type = 2;
    propItem.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(item.ToString() + "\0");
    propItem.Len = propItem.Value.Length;
    file.SetPropertyItem(propItem);
}
```

This is what I've researched:

[Add custom attributes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10833928/custom-exif-tags): This uses something different

[SetPropert](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/71d8de37-f52d-4faa-887a-793f8041110a/managing-general-exif-info-with-imagesetpropertyitem?forum=netfxbcl): This updates a property, I need to add a new one

[Add EXIF info](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11011915/adding-exif-info-to-images-in-c-sharp): This updates standard tags

[Add new tags](http://www.thevalvepage.com/swmonkey/2013/12/23/exif-tags-in-c/): This is what I've tried, didn work

Comment: You should provide some links to show what you have researched about this.

Comment: Can you elaborate, explaining why your research has failed to lead you to an answer?  E.g. "this site says blah blah blah but doesn't explain xyz" etc.

Comment: I wouldn't approach this with C# directly. I'd start a 3rd party process (exiftool) using `System.Diagnostics.Process` to do this for me.

Comment: You do realize that even successful changes would get discarded in your using clause?

Comment: @spender Can you give me an example please?

Comment: @TaW Yes, I know. But first I want to make it work, regardless if it gets saved or not

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually the [link](http://www.thevalvepage.com/swmonkey/2013/12/23/exif-tags-in-c/) you are using is working just fine. You did however miss one important point:

- You should set the `Id` to a suitable value; `0x9286` is 'UserComment' and certainly a good one to play with.

You can make up new Ids of your own but Exif viewers may not pick those up..

Also: You should **either** grab a valid `PropertyItem` from a **known** file! That is one you are sure that it has one. **Or, if you are sure** your target file does have ar least one `PropertyItem` you can go ahead and use it as a proptotype for the one you want to add, but you still **need** to change its `Id`.

---

```
public Form1()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    img0 = Image.FromFile(aDummyFileWithPropertyIDs);
}

Image img0 = null;

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    PropertyItem propItem = img0.PropertyItems[0];
    using (var file = Image.FromFile(yourTargetFile))
    {
        propItem.Id = 0x9286;  // this is called 'UserComment'
        propItem.Type = 2;
        propItem.Value = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(textBox1.Text + "\0");
        propItem.Len = propItem.Value.Length;
        file.SetPropertyItem(propItem);
        // now let's see if it is there: 
        PropertyItem propItem1 = file.PropertyItems[file.PropertyItems.Count()-1];
        file.Save(newFileName);
    }
}
```

There is are lists of IDs [to be found from here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms534413.aspx).

Note that you will **need** to save to a new file since you are still holding onto the old one..

You can retrieve  by their ID:

```
PropertyItem getPropertyItemByID(Image img, int Id)
{
    return img.PropertyItems.Select(x => x).FirstOrDefault(x => x.Id == Id);
}
```

and get at string values like this:

```
PropertyItem pi = getPropertyItemByID(file, 0x9999);  // ! A fantasy Id for testing!
if (pi != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine( System.Text.Encoding.Default.GetString(pi.Value));
}
```

Comment: The System.Drawing.Image type will accept and use this with any image type, but when `Save()` the image it only works with JPGs.

Comment: Exif itself was defined for jpeg and tif only. Not sure whether propertyIds can be stored e.g. in png or wihch other formats if any. A conclusive set of findings would be a nice complement to this post!

Comment: Doesn't the outlined solution decrease the image quality, since it is saving the actual image, too? I would have thought that there is a way to just modify the metadata, just like it is possible in Windows Explorer, too.

Comment: Sorry to say, but I don't know.

Comment: Great answer, thank you