# Why is the image being rotated when I only reduce the image quality?

Tags: c#, image, image-processing

I've follow this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161873/reduce-image-size-c-sharp) answer to reduce the uploaded image size. The image size is reduced but it also rotated the image itself (which it should not being rotated).

I don't see any part of the code is doing a rotation to the image and having no clue what's going on with the code.

Therefore, I am hoping may get some further explanation on what the code does and why the image is being rotated when reducing only the quality.

For convenience, I've copy the [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4161873/reduce-image-size-c-sharp) answer here

```
// Make sure to include this at the top
   using System.Drawing.Imaging;


/// <summary> 
/// Saves an image as a jpeg image, with the given quality 
/// </summary> 
/// <param name="path"> Path to which the image would be saved. </param> 
/// <param name="quality"> An integer from 0 to 100, with 100 being the highest quality. </param> 
    public static void SaveJpeg (string path, Image img, int quality) 
    { 
        if (quality<0  ||  quality>100) 
        throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("quality must be between 0 and 100."); 

        // Encoder parameter for image quality 
        EncoderParameter qualityParam = new EncoderParameter(Encoder.Quality, quality); 
       // JPEG image codec 
       ImageCodecInfo jpegCodec = GetEncoderInfo("image/jpeg"); 
       EncoderParameters encoderParams = new EncoderParameters(1); 
       encoderParams.Param[0] = qualityParam; 
       img.Save(path, jpegCodec, encoderParams); 
    } 

/// <summary> 
/// Returns the image codec with the given mime type 
/// </summary> 
    private static ImageCodecInfo GetEncoderInfo(string mimeType) 
    { 
        // Get image codecs for all image formats 
        ImageCodecInfo[] codecs = ImageCodecInfo.GetImageEncoders(); 

        // Find the correct image codec 
        for(int i=0; i<codecs.Length; i++) 
           if(codecs[i].MimeType == mimeType) 
               return codecs[i]; 

         return null; 
     }
```

Comment: Maybe the code loses an exif rotation tag. test e.g. in irfanview!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get Image Orientation and rotate as per orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835064/get-image-orientation-and-rotate-as-per-orientation)

Comment: @TaW You are right! I uploaded original and re-qualify image to exifdata.com, the exif rotation tag is missing in the latter. May I know is there a way to preserve this exif rotation tag when changing the quality of the image?

Comment: @mjwills The [Get Image Orientation and rotate as per orientation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27835064/get-image-orientation-and-rotate-as-per-orientation) did not answer my question as I didn't change the rotation of the image, but somehow the rotation of the image has changed after I reduce the image quality.

Comment: [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42971094/getting-correct-image-rotation/42972969#42972969) shows how to modify the exif rotation tag. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35295284/how-to-add-custom-exif-tags-to-a-image/35298122#35298122).is another post to show how to add a new propertyitem. Not sure where the code you have loses the propertyitems or exif tags, though..

Comment: Hm, I just tested the code you posted and the results are confusing. While not all tags seem to be preserved most are  the Orientation tag most definitely is. I used a simple test: `string infile = "D:\\xtest.jpg"; - How did you read the file?
int q = trackBar1.Value;
Image img = Image.FromFile(infile);
SaveJpeg("D:\\xtest" + q + ".jpg", img, q);`

Comment: I doubt if is has something to do with the OS. I am currently using Mac Book to run VS for Mac when testing the code. Here is the sample I read the file and pass to the SaveJpeg method: `Image myImage = Image.FromFile("/Users/name/img.jpg");
SaveJpeg("/Users/name/newimg.jpg", myImage,50);`

Comment: I also checked the links you share here. I try to look into the image object after I read from the directory, the `PropertyItems` are empty, I think it has already lose the exif data when reading the image file.

Comment: `did not answer my question` You have two broad approaches if something is rotated via exif rotation data. One is to re-apply the exif after changing image quality (which most of the other comments are advocating). The other approach is to rotate **while changing image quality** (which removes the need for the exif data in the new image). My link may be helpful if you prefer that latter approach.