# How to get response data consisting both image file and values in flask server post response?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, image, flask

Sending image to the flask server and do object detection on that and send back that image as a response and no of object detected variable value. Flask route function is as below

```
@app.route('/upload', methods=['POST'])
def upload_file():
    file = request.files['image']
    im = Image.open(file)


    total_count = 0
    for i in keypoints:
        total_count = total_count + 1
    im_with_keypoints = cv2.drawKeypoints(im, keypoints, np.array([]), (0, 0, 255), cv2.DRAW_MATCHES_FLAGS_DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS)
    file_object = io.BytesIO()
    img = Image.fromarray(im_with_keypoints.astype('uint8'))

    # write PNG in file-object
    img.save(file_object, 'JPEG')

    # move to beginning of file so `send_file()` it will read from start    
    file_object.seek(0)

    return send_file(file_object, mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

when I do post a request by uploading an image I get the processed image back on POSTMAN
but I need to get the value of variable total_count along with the image.
I tried calling like this

```
return '{} {}'.format(total_count,send_file(file_object, mimetype='image/jpeg'))
```

but I got output as `11 <Response streamed [200 OK]>`
where the image is stored as object form, is there a way to get the image along with the total_count value as a response?
Any suggestion or example on the way of getting both response which is Image and variable total_count?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

mclslee's suggestions are quite creative/clever but they feel a bit hacky to me. Here are my ideas:

### Base64-encoded image

Code stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/31826470/220652

```
from flask import jsonify
import base64
# other imports

# ...

base64_image = base64.b64encode(file_object.getvalue())
return jsonify(image=base64_image, total_count=total_count)
```

And it doesn't need to be JSON:

```
return f"{total_count} {base64_image}"
```

You haven't said anything about the client, it'd obviously need to know how to *decode* base64 data but most platforms [including JS in the browser](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Basics_of_HTTP/Data_URIs) can do that.

### Image with EXIF tag

Idea stolen from https://stackoverflow.com/a/10834464/220652

Requirement: https://pypi.org/project/exif/

```
import json
from exif import Image as ExifImage
# other imports

# ...

exif_image = ExifImage(file_object)
# Either ... or ... (no idea whether either works)
exif_image.maker_note = json.dumps(dict(total_count=total_count))
exif_image.user_comment = json.dumps(dict(total_count=total_count))
return send_file(io.BytesIO(exif_image.get_file()), mimetype='image/jpeg')
```

Here as well the client needs to know how to read EXIF tags from images and again most platforms [including JS in the browser](https://github.com/exif-js/exif-js) can do that.

Answer (score 0):

Off the top of my head, there are a couple of things you could do, below are pseudocoded-ish versions:

- Make a custom header in the response and grab it from the headers with whatever is calling this endpoint

```
from flask import make_response, send_file    

...

response = make_response(send_file(file_object, mimetype='image/jpeg'))
response.headers['Total-Count'] = total_count #might have to make it a string
return response
```

or

- Send the file with the total_count as part of the filename and parse it out from whatever is calling this endpoint

```
from flask import send_file

...

file_name = f"{total_count}_image.jpeg"
return send_file(file_object, mimetype="image/jpeg", as_attachment=True, attachment_filename=file_name)
```